# How to get the URL with a print preview of an Outlook 365 message with OfficeJS?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm creating an Outlook add-ins using OfficeJS and I need to get the URL of the print preview view of a message.

Here's an example of what I want

The original message

[image]

and here is the print preview of the message

[image]

How I can get the URL of the print preview?

---

**More info about the scenario:**

I'm creating an outlook add-in that must be installed in Outlook 365 and Outlook Desktop 2016.

I'm using Office.js for the development.

When the user clicks a button in the addin, I need to send the whole message to a Web API as a file.

Currently, I get all the info from the message, but it is separated by pieces: the *To, CC, Subject, Body* from *Office.context.mailbox.item* programmatically. I need it all as a single file (html, pdf or any standard format).

Comment: @vcRobe, currently, there is no way to get print preview page for the selected message. Can you share some more information about your the scenario you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information provided, it seems like you want to transmit the message. You could do this by using Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId convert the id to a REST id using Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId and then do a get using REST use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_get.